# On a touch device, where the scroll was created with javascript, how to prevent touch triggering click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got an app developed in AngularJs and iScroll is being used, to create a scroller on a list or grid. When touching and dragging while scrolling some times it triggers the "click" event on nested elements.

My question is, how to avoid this to happen ?

```
$('.foo').on('click', function(e){ ... });
```

Let's say the list looks like this:

```
<div id="iscroll_instance_will_work_here">
   <div class="scrollable">
      <ul>
        <li class="foo"> ... </li>
        <li class="foo"> ... </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for looking!

/*** UPDATE ****/

The user Rob suggested, and works nicely, here's an example:

```
                document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    console.log("touchStart triggered!");

                    $('html').addClass('isDragging');

                }, false);

                document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    console.log("touchEnd triggered!");

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('html').removeClass('isDragging');
                    }, 200);

                }, false);
```

You can remove the timeout! In my case makes it work better ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothetically, you can set a variable or class on drag start or whatever. Then in your .foo click event function, if your dragstart reference is true, e.preventDefault().

Then be sure to unset the variable or remove the class on drag stop.

Comment: @helrida, if this answer addresses your question, you can accept it.